# Deny access for specific search query

Tags: php

I want to stop access for specific search queries on Google CSE
For e.g. search query "xxx"
I have added below php code on top of search page

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['q'];
if ($url == 'xxx') {
  return 403;
}
?>
```

It worked for search query "xxx", if search query like "get xxx movies" or "xxx videos" or any other combination, how can I deny it. Also, how to deny for multiple search queries like "xxx" or "xxx1" or "xxx2" etc.

I have tried below code

```
if( strpos(file_get_contents("ban.txt"),$_GET['q']) !== false) {
return 403;
}
ban.txt
XXX
xxx
xXx
```

But, this returns error 403 for only query `XXX or xxx or xXx` does not work for search query like `"get xxx movies"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check the contents of a string.

```
$url = $_GET['q'];
if (strpos($url, 'xxx') !== FALSE) {
  return 403;
}
```

Comment: This worked, just want to ask how code will be for either xxx or xx1 or xxx2, I am beginner in php

Comment: `xxx` and `xxx2` will return the 403 error, `xx1` won't. The function only searches specifically for `xxx`.

Comment: Is it possible to import text file which will contain all possible search terms added 1 term in each row to block. Because, if someone will try `Xxx` or `xXx` etc. variations, it can be better to put all in text file.

Comment: Just look at my answer, you can use `stristr` that is case insensitive. And yes, you can read a file with `file_get_contents` and with a simple `explode('\n', $file)` you will get the array to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function or [stristr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php).

Little example here:

```
if (strstr($_GET['var'])) 
    return 403;
```

But, IMHO, you can think something better than this rude check...